# Structr - which version of Neo4j to use

Tags: java, neo4j, structr

Windows 7, java 8, Neo4j 3.0.0-M03, initial install of structr.

When I first try to run the program I'm getting this error:

SEVERE: Vital service HttpService failed to start: No resource provider available for servlet JsonRestServlet. Aborting

Reading the Google Groups the report is that structr is only good up to 2.2.6 - looking at the [Neo4j Release Page](http://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/) 2.2.6 has been skipped - it goes from 2.1.8 to 2.2.8.

My question is what version should I use?

Also - is java 7 still a requirement? Looking at the Oracle website I'm seeing that 7 has been deprecated and won't be patched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most recent pre-built versions of Structr are built against and embed Neo4j 2.2.8.

To use with custom Neo4j versions, you can to build your own driver, see https://github.com/structr/structr-neo4j-driver. Should work with any 2.x version of Neo4j.

On the Java side, Java JDK 8 is a requirement.

Comment: Thanks! Also, the web page says Java 7 is the requirement, so if that's changed then the web page needs to be tweaked.

Comment: The new documentation site is about to be launched. To get preview access, register at https://support.structr.com (free).

Comment: For an updated documentatin, please go to https://support.structr.com/article/258.